# how to configuration value.yaml when helm charts upgrade ignore specific pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, upgrade

How to configure a specific pod component to be ignored when using helm upgrade
so that it does not follow.

```
For example a charts: abc.tgz  
This charts contains three components, a-pod,b-pod,c-pod; 

helm upgrade xx abc.tgz -n xxx -f new_values.yaml
```

how to configure new_values.yaml,
so that upgrade only follows new a,b;
nothing is done to c-pod,
unless c-pod is not present, then it is rebuilt.

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?  `helm upgrade` will always try to send everything in the chart to the cluster (if it's bare Pods it will probably fail to modify them; typically use Deployments instead) and you can't make it selectively not update some things.  But conversely, if the Deployment `c` is unmodified, then there's no harm in sending it to the cluster.

Comment: ```helm version:v2.14.1  kubectl version:v1.15.6 and a-deploymen-pod, b-deployment-pod, c-deployment-pod```  If you split the charts package adc.tgz into ab.tgz and c.tgz or put the c part in requirements.yaml, it is easier to solve this problem.
But I would like to know if there are other tricks that helm can do to achieve this. For example, as you mentioned, if the deployment c is not changed, during testing, you will still trigger the rebuild of c when you upgrade with new charts abc.tgz.